# Set-User: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Title' using Connect-ExchangeOnline

Tags: powershell, scripting, office365, exchange-server

I am writing a script that will update Exchange mailbox attributes from a CSV file. When I run my script I get a 'A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Title'." error. Any ideas. I am tring to change The title property within the organisation tab in Exchange.

I know what the error message means but I can't find anywhere what the syntax is for changing the title attribute.

Script:

```
# Updates AD user attributes from CSV file


$Credential = Get-Credential
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Credential

# Load data from file.csv
$ADUsers = Import-csv file_path

# Count variable for number of users update
$count = 0

# Go through each row that has user data in the CSV we just imported 
ForEach($User in $ADUsers)
{
    # Ppopulate hash table for Get-ADUser splatting:
    $GetParams =
    @{
        Identity     = $User.Username
    }

    # Initialize hash table for Set-ADUser splatting:
    $SetParams =
    @{
        Title        = $User.Title  
    }

    # Check to see if the user already exists in AD. If they do, we update.
    if ( Get-EXORecipient @GetParams)
    {
         # Set User attributes
         Set-User @SetParams -WhatIf

         # Print that the user was updated 
         Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "$User - User attributes have been updated." 

         # Update Count
         $count += 1    
     }
}

# Print the number of updated users
Write-Host $count "Users have been updated" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Error Message:

```
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Title'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: From your error, it looks like we aren't seeing the whole script unless I am just an idiot... Your error lies at the command ```PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -ExchangeEnvironmentName $ExchangeEnviro...```

Comment: That command might be run by `Connect-ExchangeOnline`, @Neko Musume

Comment: @AdminOfThings i didn't want to but the actual server address. I don't think I need that line anyway. But that is not where the problem lies.

Comment: @NekoMusume that command is run by Connect-ExchangeOnline. This is the full script

Comment: Your credential format is wrong. `$Credential` needs to contain a username in the proper format. That is usually the UserPrincipalName (`user@domain.com`). Entering just `userID` as the username yields the same error you see.

Comment: @AdminOfThings that is the admins credentials and is populated by a prompt

Comment: @Clancinio and the error suggests it was entered incorrectly.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I had to using different credentials. Thanks. But now another error. Great.

Comment: New question continuing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62519643/new-exopssession-error-when-using-connect-exchangeonline-command-in-powershell)?

Comment: @NekoMusume I still think it is the same problem. When you enter `userid` as the username, you get this error. When you enter `domain\userid`, you get the new error. `UserPrincipalName` needs to be used. I want to see the format of `$credential` username.

Comment: @AdminOfThings by using the email format I got passed that error. Thank you. But now I am getting the update error as shown above I can't find anywhere where it says what the property name is for changing the title..

Comment: @Clancinio, use Set-User for changing title (or Set-AdUser for hybrid organization)

Comment: @robdy I changed my code to Set-User but still no luck. Same error message. I am wondering is Get-EXORecipient the correct command I am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your params for `Set-User` doesn't contain `-Identity` so PowerShell doesn't know to whom the title should be set. You need to add it:

```bsh
$SetParams =
@{
    Identity     = $User.Username
    Title        = $User.Title  
}
```

Make sure that `Username` contains valid identity, so the user can be determined based on it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. But also, I needed to run it in the Exchange Management Shell.

Comment: Running in Exchange Management Shell I used Get-Mailbox and Set-User. Worked fine.