# New-ExoPSSession error when using Connect-ExchangeOnline command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting, exchange-server

I am trying to connect to PowerShell using the Connect-ExchangeOnline command but I receive the following error. Any ideas?

```
New-ExoPSSession : . 
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\1.0.1\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:445 char:30
+ ... PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -ExchangeEnvironmentName $ExchangeEnviro ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-ExoPSSession], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellSnapin.NewExoPSSession
```

Comment: Please show the format of the credential you are entering. Typically, the credential username is the `UserPrincipalName` value of that account. Just `userid` won't work. The `SamAccountName` generally won't work because if it is an AD on-prem account, the `SamAccountName` value does not match what is in Azure. When it comes to cloud accounts, the `SamAccountName` is often not what you expect it to be. `UserPrincipalName` (UPN)  is predictable and should be consistent from on-prem to Azure (if in hybrid mode) or if created in the cloud. The UPN format looks like an email address.

Comment: Connecting to ExchangeOnline using a username in the format of `domain\userid` can create this error.

Comment: @AdminOfThings yes I am using format domain/userid. So I should use my company email is what you are saying??

Comment: Creating multiple questions for the same problem doesn't help anything. Generally, help is provided very quickly. Trust me when I say that your questions don't get lost in the pile. If they go unanswered, they are either too complex for a quick answer or you aren't providing enough information. This is the situation of you not providing enough information.

Comment: typically the email format matches the UPN. I would start with email address if you are unsure of the UPN value.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I appreciate all your help and I will add as much information as possible to my next questions

Comment: I am not the authority for asking questions, but it is okay to edit a question and add more information or provide updated information based on steps you have tried. Evolving the question's data is sometimes necessary for a solution to be found. What people generally don't like is expecting more than the question requires. You don't want to flood the post with too much unnecessary information either. There is a balance and comments help position the focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use the cmdlet as follows:

```
Connect-IPPSSession -PSSessionOption
$EXOSession = New-ExoPSSession -pssessionoption
Import-PSSession $EXOSession -Prefix EXO
```

Comment: Are those three separate commands, or just one command on three lines?  Whichever way I try them, I get errors.

Comment: These commands should try one by one. So three commands al together

Answer (score 2):

The newest version of Exchange Online module requires PowerShell V7.  As soon as I installed V7 it worked fine.

Per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps#install-and-maintain-the-exo-v2-module

> EXO V2 module is supported in PowerShell 7.0.3 or later

Comment: Fixed it for me as well, would not have thought to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve a similar issue by switching my default web browser in Windows 10 to the Chromium Edge browser. I brought up the login window once, then switched Firefox back to my default browser and it still worked.

PowerShell v7 is not required to use the ExchangeOnlineManagement module, but is an acceptable workaround. It uses the account logged into the default web browser for authentication, which wasn't an acceptable solution for me. It led me to switching the default browser, though, which resolved my initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that I use to connect.  Please fill in your default username and make sure to run the prerequisites in the comments at the top (review first of course)

- [WMF 5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616)
- [.Net 4.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653)

And if you're using this non-interactive you'll want to look up how to [store your credentials securely](https://purple.telstra.com.au/blog/using-saved-credentials-securely-in-powershell-scripts) and how to [use](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/cred-get-credential-without-asking-for-prompts-in-powershell/m-p/483570/highlight/true#M21869) those stored credentials, replacing the `Get-Credential` section with your configuration

```
# Requires: .Net 4.5, Windows Management Framework 5.1 (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps )
#
# Run Once:
#  Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned; Get-ExecutionPolicy
#  Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force
#  Install-Module –Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
#
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/exchange-online-powershell-v2/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps



$exo = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    $UserName = "Default.Username@domain"
    $UserCredential = Get-Credential -message "Enter 365 admin credentials" -UserName $UserName
    function IsConnected(){
        try{
            if (
                @($(get-mailbox -resultsize 1 -WarningAction silentlycontinue)).count `
                -eq
                1
            ) {return $true}
        }
        catch {}
        return $false
    }

    function Connect(){
        $result = "Unfinished"
        if ($this.IsConnected()) {
            $result = "Success"
        } else {
            $UserCredential = $this.UserCredential
            Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential
            if ($this.IsConnected()) {
                $result = "Success"
            } else {
                $result = "Fail"
            }
        }
        switch($result){
            "Unfinished" {Write-Warning "`nAn unknown error occured in .Connect(), Appears to have ended while unfinished";break}
            "Success" {Write-host "`nSuccessfully connected to Exchange 365";break}
            "Fail" {Write-Warning "`nFailed to connect to Exchange 365";break}
            default {write-warning "`nAn unknown error occured in .Connect(), result code unrecognized";break}
        }
        # old style
        #$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
        #Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
    }

    function ConnectMsol(){
        Connect-MsolService -Credential $UserCredential
    }

    function Disconnect(){
        Disconnect-ExchangeOnline
        # old sytle
        #Remove-PSSession $Session
    }

    function Cycle(){
        $this.Disconnect()
        $this.Connect()
    }
    Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable *
}

$exo.Connect()
#$exo.ConnectMsol()

<#
# --- Azure AD ---
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell#connect-with-the-azure-active-directory-powershell-for-graph-module
# --- Azure AD ---
#>
```

Comment: Hopefully it's clear in the script, but this creates an $exo object with which you can call `$exo.Connect()`, `$exo.Disconnect()`, `$exo.Cycle()` and `$exo.IsConnected()`

Comment: This is so painful.  All I'm trying to do is to show a mailbox that is hidden in the Exchange Management Console because I removed the user's license. It turns out you have to use Power Shell to do that (why?) and then you have to write a script to do it? Could they make simple tasks any more complicated?

Comment: The script failed with:

Exception calling "Connect" with "0" arguments:  Create Powershell Session is failed using Oauth at logon.ps1:64:1
Exo.Connnect()

Comment: Did you make to run all 3 "run once" lines and made sure you have both Powershell 5 (or above) and .Net 4.5?  If so then [another user](https://blog.bjornhouben.com/2017/03/16/office-365-create-powershell-session-is-failed-using-oauth-when-trying-to-connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/) had a similar issue and had to uninstall then re-install the [exchange online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps) powershell module

Comment: The script is to store the credentials and simplify additional connections.  It disconnects you really fast now so I found it convenient to have a simple way to reconnect.  It simplifies out to `$UserCredential = Get-Credential; Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $UserCredential`

Comment: Yes, I ran the three Run Once commands.  I do not know how to check the version of PowerShell or .Net.  I don't even know what .Net is and I don't see it in the list of programs in Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224701/discussion-between-chris-rudd-and-zkilnbqi).

Comment: After working on this a bit it seems there may be a [conflict](https://blog.ciaops.com/2019/07/24/exchange-online-powershell-winrm-issue/) caused by some of the Microsoft Intune settings

Comment: Removing the security baseline from Intune and resyncing by rebooting fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the security baseline from Intune and resyncing by rebooting fixed the issue in my case.